# How can I get ttyUSB log with timestamp in llinux

Tags: linux, logging, terminal

The following logs is from [TeraTerm](https://en.osdn.jp/projects/ttssh2/), a terminal emulator for windows.
I want to get log from ttyUSB0 in my Linux in the following way.

```
[Thu Apr 14 15:08:14.410 2016] Load U-Boot from eMMC/NAND Flash
[Thu Apr 14 15:08:14.410 2016] eMMC/NAND copy from 0x030A0000 to 0x49FB0000 (len:262144).
[Thu Apr 14 15:08:14.456 2016] Done.
[Thu Apr 14 15:08:14.456 2016] 
[Thu Apr 14 15:08:14.456 2016] 
[Thu Apr 14 15:08:14.456 2016] U-Boot 1.2.0 (Sep  2 2013 - 13:31:42)Puma6 - PSPU-Boot 2.0.0.24
[Thu Apr 14 15:08:14.503 2016] 
[Thu Apr 14 15:08:14.503 2016] DRAM:  128 MB
[Thu Apr 14 15:08:14.503 2016] *** Warning - Unsupported Flash detected, flash is unusable
[Thu Apr 14 15:08:14.503 2016]
```

I found [this document](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Logging), but it gives timestamp when a terminal is idle.

```
-- 0:ttyUSB2 -- time-stamp -- 2016-04-15 17:23:13 --
-- 0:ttyUSB2 -- time-stamp -- 2016-04-15 17:23:53 --
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is off topic here. Please ask it on Supper User.

Comment: Thanks, @hein. I copied this question to [superuser/q/1067998](http://superuser.com/questions/1067998).

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to do so. I have data coming through serial port. The output originally (using /dev/ttyUSB0)looks as below.

```
Sending struct (10 bytes) ... 

A: -0.06.

Sending struct (10 bytes) ... 

A: -0.05.

Sending struct (10 bytes) ... 

A: -0.06.


Sending struct (10 bytes) ... 

A: -0.05.
```

After using the following command I get timestaps.

```
awk '{ print strftime("[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%f %y]"), $0; }' /dev/ttyUSB0 > /home/captain/ttyUSB0_v11.txt &
```

The output looks as below.

```
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:03.%f 19] 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:03.%f 19] Transmitting at 868 Mhz...
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:03.%f 19] 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:03.%f 19] SPI Flash Init OK ... UniqueID (MAC): A: -0.06.
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:03.%f 19] 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:03.%f 19] Sending struct (10 bytes) ... 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:03.%f 19] 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:04.%f 19] A: -0.05.
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:04.%f 19] 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:04.%f 19] Sending struct (10 bytes) ... 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:04.%f 19] 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:05.%f 19] A: -0.06.
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:05.%f 19] 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:06.%f 19] Sending struct (10 bytes) ... 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:06.%f 19] 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:07.%f 19] A: -0.06.
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:07.%f 19] 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:07.%f 19] Sending struct (10 bytes) ... 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:07.%f 19] 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:08.%f 19] A: -0.06.
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:08.%f 19] 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:08.%f 19] Sending struct (10 bytes) ... 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:08.%f 19] 
[Thu Sep 26 12:01:09.%f 19] A: -0.05.
```

For some weird reason, milliseconds (%f) didn't work. But you should be able to figure that out if it's very important.

Cheers

OS- Ubuntu14.04

Serial Device - Moteino (Arduino)